# Sorting using lambda function in c++

Tags: c++, sorting

I don't understand what is wrong with the following simple sorting code. It compiles but produce a segmentation fault when I try to run it.

I know there are other ways of doing the same kind of sorting, and the values that I'm using are all the same (so, there's nothing to sort), but I would like to understand why it produce a segmentation fault.

There is no problem if I use `w[1][i]>w[1][j]` instead of `w[1][i]>=w[1][j]` in the comparator.

```
vector<int> a(100);
iota(a.begin(),a.end(),0);
vector<vector<int> >  w(2,vector<int>(100,1));
sort(a.begin(),a.end(),[&w](const int i,const int j){return w[0][i]>w[0][j] || (w[0][i]==w[0][j] && w[1][i]>=w[1][j]);});
```

Comment: So what were the values of `i` and `j` when it crashed? You can see exactly what happened to cause a SEGV by running under a debugger, or by dumping a core file and opening _that_ in the debugger.

Comment: Greater-or-equal violates the strict weak ordering required for `std::sort`. Therefore such a comparison will invoke undefined behavior when using that algorithm. You do not (and should not) need to test for direct or partial equivalence. All you should care about overall is `is-less-than` and return true in said condition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 5):

Your lambda does not provide a strict weak ordering, violating the contract the `std::sort` has.  This means the code has undefined behavior and a segmentation fault is a possible outcome of that.  With strict weak ordering if `a < b` is `true` then `b < a` must be `false`.  That doesn't happen here.  No matter what `i` and `j` are

```
w[0][i]>w[0][j] || (w[0][i]==w[0][j] && w[1][i]>=w[1][j])
```

turns into

```
1 > 1 || (1 == 1 && 1 >= 1)
```

which is

```
false || (true && true)
```

which is just `true`.  If `i` and `j` (`a` and `b`) get swapped around, you still get the same result.  When you use `>` instead of `>=` then `1 > 1` is `false` causing the lambda to return `false`and `sort` says that all of the items are equal.